# Understanding this regex example

Tags: javascript, regex

The following example is **javascript** code that uses **regex**:

```
// Make a regular expression object that matches
// a JavaScript string.
var my_regexp = /"(?:\\.|[^\\\"])*"/g;
```

My current understanding of the previous regex example (`/"(?:\\.|[^\\\"])*"/g`) is as follows:

- `/` at the beginning and at the end denote the beginning and end of the regular expression that is going to be matched with some string.
- the `g` at the end is a **flag** with the following definition:

> Global (match multiple times; the precise meaning of this varies with
>   the method)

So basically it's meaning depends on the functions I use the **regex** variable in.

- `(?:...)` denotes a non-capturing group, where the expression that stands in the place of `...` will match either **zero** or **one** time.

**MY FIRST DOUBT:** I have seen a different syntax for non-capturing groups: `(?:...)?` which has a `?` at the end. Is there a difference between that and no `?` at the end? is the `*` replacing the `?` to make it equate to **zero** or **more** rather than **zero** or **one**?

- The inside of the non-capturing group is `\\.|[^\\\"]`. The `[^\\\"]` is pretty clear in specifying any character besides \(backslash) and "(quotations).

**MY LAST DOUBT:** The last thing I don't understand here are the four characters: `\\.|`. `\\` equates to a backslash, and `.` I believe equates to any character, and `|` I'm not sure. I'm pretty sure that the inside of the non-capturing group isn't specifying to search for characters in a string that have `\[anything]|[anything except for \ and "]` because the comments in the example above literally says: `// Make a regular expression object that matches a Javascript string.`

**QUESTION:** Would anyone be able to clarify the doubts I am having above?

Comment: `|` called OR operator  in regex.. `(?:\\.|[^\\\"])*` matches any escaped character like `\\"`, `\\'` greedily and if the following char is not any escaped character then the control moves to the next pattern `[^\\\"]`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Oh nice, thank you!

Comment: Paste your `regex` into [regexr](http://regexr.com/) and you can hover over your `regex` for detail explanation of each character/caption group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A group starting with `(?:` is, as you say a **non capturing group**. It means that the part it matches, isn't stored in a capture group, available for later retrieval. Making a group **optional** with a `?`, means the part it's *supposed* to match, isn't necessary for the *whole* regex to match. It's not uncommon for non-capturing groups to be optional.

The **alternation** feature matches the sequence on either side of it, starting by trying with the left side.

So your regex matches a string

- starting with a `"`, then either
- an escaped character **or**
- a character that isn't a `\` or a `"`.
- finally ending with a `"`.

PS. You don't need to escape the `"` inside the character class. `/"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*"/g` is OK.